# Can we use node.js as server side launguage for mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

One of my client asking they are developing a app using node.js and
MongoDB. So this means there is no server side code like java or php
or .NET? Or can we use this node.js as serverside code? I am new to node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js lets you execute javascript outside the browser. It has a huge amount of code, libraries, and packages. You can run a server on node, so yes, that means you don't need java or php.

Google is your friend: https://nodejs.org/en/

Javascript on nodejs is very fast (almost as fast as C).

Comment: Do you have any reliable data on this?

Comment: I haven't done the test myself, but have found similar quotes frequently. I'm thinking of doing some benchmarking myself. I cannot find the original reference that I found but found this: http://blog.carlesmateo.com/2014/10/13/performance-of-several-languages/